# Some basic exercise on struct

Tags: c#

Alright, this is the exercise:
Set a struct called "Date" that contains date, including: year, month and day. Also, define a class called "Phone" that contains a name, number, date of birth and address. Need to create an array that contains objects of type Phone and sort them by name, number, and date.
This is my code:

```
struct Date
{
    int year, month, day;
    public Date(int year, int month, int day)
    {
        this.year = year;
        this.month = month;
        this.day = day;
    }
}
class Phone
{
    int number;
    string birthday, adress, name;
    public Phone(int number, string birthday, string adress, string name)
    {
        this.number = number;
        this.birthday = birthday;
        this.adress = adress;
        this.name = name;
    }
}
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Phone[] p = new Phone[3];
        for (int i = 0; i < p.Length; i++)
        {
        }
    }
}
```

So, the thing is that I don't know how to get the struct date from the "Phone" class.
It suppose to be something like this right? birthday.year, and such.
Thanks.

Comment: You should take a hint from the fact that the birthday is called "Date of birth". You created a Date struct...now use it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've declared `birthday` as a `string`.

You need to declare it as a `Date`.

Answer (score 1):

Well, you've currently got `birthday` as a string - I suspect you actually want that to be a `Date`, right? Make both the field and the constructor parameter a `Date`.

You should also almost certainly have "getter" properties for all the values - otherwise you can't get at any of the data once you've created the struct instance.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you're trying to do here.  You're passing your "birthday" as a string, not as an instance of 'Date.'

If you want birthday to be a Date you'd need to do this:

```
public class Phone
{
    public int Number {get; set;}
    public string Name {get; set;}
    public Date Birthday {get; set;}
    public string Address {get; set;}

    public Phone(int number, Date birthday, string name, string address) 
    { /* your implementation here */ }
}
```

If you wanted to pass a string to your Phone constructor for the birthday, you'd need something on the Date Struct to convert it:

```
public Phone(int, number, string birthday, string name, string address)
{
    Number = number;
    Birthday = Date.FromString(birthday);
    Name = name;
    Address = address;
}
```

and that `Date.FromString(string date)` would be a method in your Struct.

Answer (score 0):

You should declare your birthday variable as a Date. You wouldn't be needing the struct.